# Updating user ProxyAddresses

Tags: powershell

I try to update AD user account ProxyAddresses property. I've read many topics about this and applied one of the suggested approach ([this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3970a4a-287c-4029-af89-5904a55b3a61/change-primary-smtp-in-proxyaddresses-ad-attribute?forum=winserverpowershell)) but it doesn't work for me. Why?
I use a following bit of code (it's a part of script updating more users data):

```
$ADUser = SearchADUser -Kogo "sAMAccountName -eq '$($WzorUser.sAMAccountName)'"
...
1.$ProxyOK = $false
2.$Proxies = $ADUser.ProxyAddresses
3.$Proxies | ForEach-Object {
4.  $_ = $_ -replace 'SMTP', 'smtp'
5.  if ($_ -match $NoweMail) {
6.      $_ = $_ -replace 'smtp', 'SMTP'
7.      $ProxyOK = $true
8.  }
9.}
10.if (!($ProxyOK)) { $Proxies += ("SMTP:$($NoweMail)") }
...
if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Proxies))) {
    $AttrToReplace.Add("ProxyAddresses", $Proxies)
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountName -Server $ADDC @Attr #-PassThru -WhatIf
```

When looping on Proxies, its elements are properly processed: letters are lowercased for all and uppercased if the new mail was already present.
But Proxies is not changed. Do each element needs to be saved in some way or replaced in the object?

**Update 2020-04-02**

Because supporter effort (@Theo once again thanks for Your assist) focus on replacing method I try to more detailed explain my problem.

Target user proxyAddresses values (it's a rare case when women come back to her maiden name alredy recorded in AD):

**SMTP**:anna.nowak22@lp.pl

**smtp**:a.b@moc.com

Initial  values (line 2):

```
[DBG]: PS X:\>> $Proxies
smtp:anna.nowak22@lp.pl
SMTP:a.b@moc.com
```

While looping on every proxy element (line 9):

```
[DBG]: PS X:\>> $_
SMTP:anna.nowak22@lp.pl
[DBG]: PS X:\>> $Proxies
smtp:anna.nowak22@lp.pl
SMTP:a.b@moc.com

[DBG]: PS X:\>> $_
smtp:a.b@moc.com
[DBG]: PS X:\>> $Proxies
smtp:anna.nowak22@lp.pl
SMTP:a.b@moc.com
```

As can be seen $Proxies doesn't reflect changes.

If there was only one ProxyAddresses value not equal with new mail, new mail was added as SMTP to the existed one which is leaved also as SMTP (two primary ProxyAddresses).

I tried to create a new variable and assign to it each value respectively but I don't know how to handle it.

```
$newProxies = $null
$Proxies | ForEach-Object {
    $_ = $_ -creplace 'SMTP', 'smtp'
    if ($_ -match $NoweMail) {
        $_ = $_ -creplace 'smtp', 'SMTP'
        $ProxyOK = $true
    }
      $newProxies.add($_)
}
```

Above generates an error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

`$newProxies += $_` creates one string *SMTP:anna.nowak22@lp.pl
smtp:a.b@moc.com* which is added as single ProxyAddress.

As I noted $Proxies is a special AD object and I don't know how to create an object of such type and how to add new elements to it.

Comment: I usually clear the existing ProxyAddresses for the user and then add the new proxies array: `Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountName -Clear ProxyAddresses` followed by `Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies}`. P.S. `-replace` is case insensitive. In this case I would prefer using `-creplace`. Also the test for the empty $Proxies array is redundant. If you must, use `if ($Proxies)` or `if ($Proxies.Count)`

Comment: @Theo.
Replaces work fine. Each element of Proxies is processed well. Fist lowercased and then uppercased if matches pattern. After replacements variable $_ is correct cased. But it doesn't update Proxies.

Comment: That is why I showed you how I do it. In your code, you are adding the $Proxies to a Hashtable (?) called `$AttrToReplace`, but in the Set-ADUser cmdlet you use another variable `Attr`. The point I want to make is that you reset the ProxyAddresses array separate from all other attributes you want to set for the user (if any). Do `$ADUser | Set-ADUser -Clear ProxyAddresses` followed by `$ADUser | Set-ADUser  -Add @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies}` You can do it in one command: `$ADUser | Set-ADUser  -Replace @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies}`, but I always like to clear this first.

Comment: Have you seen my update? It deals with recreating the `$Proxies` as you want them. Finally, the collection to add needs to be a **strongly typed** string collection. For that, cast the array with `[string[]]$Proxies` as you have already tested out. Your latest code will not work, because the variable `$newProxies` is nothing at the time you try the `.add` method on it.

Comment: Yes. I'e checked it in test environment and it works fine. Ive created a $newProxies as an array and rewrite to it  $_ respectively. I was doing it before but can't apply to user account. The [string[]]$newProxies did it. Tomorrow I will. probably, test it in prouction then I post the answer. Thank You again for help. What does it mean a strongly typed string collection?

Comment: Great. If you feel my answer solved your problem,  please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark icon next to  it.

Comment: Strongly typed means the collection can only have elements of the specified type, in this case `string`. An ordinary array can contain a mix of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, here more readable as answer.

In your code, you add the modified `$Proxies` array to a hashtable (i think) called `$AttrToReplace`. However, in the final `Set-ADUser` command, you are not using this, but instead splat using a variable `@Attr`.

To update the multivalued attribute ProxyAddresses, change the code after the three dots in your question from:

```
if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Proxies))) {
    $AttrToReplace.Add("ProxyAddresses", $Proxies)
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountName -Server $ADDC @Attr #-PassThru -WhatIf
```

into:

```
# no need to test if $Proxies is an empty array, because 
# it will at the very least have "SMTP:$($NoweMail)"
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Clear ProxyAddresses
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies | ForEach-Object { "$_" }}

# or do this on one line:
# Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies | ForEach-Object { "$_" }}
```

---

**Update**

From your comments, your code does leave room for duplicate proxy addresses.

You can get this list, replace all existing `SMTP:` by `smtp:` and add the new primary email address to it like this:

```
# get the current ProxyAddress values for this user, change all values 
# that begin with uppercase 'SMTP:' to lowercase 'smtp:'.
# skip any proxy that is equal to "smtp:$NoweMail", add the $NoweMail 
# preceeded by 'SMTP:' to the list and sort or select unique
$Proxies = @($ADUser.ProxyAddresses -replace '^SMTP:', 'smtp:' |
           Where-Object { $_ -ne "smtp:$NoweMail" }) + "SMTP:$NoweMail" | Sort-Object -Unique


# set the new proxy addresses in the user attribute
# no need to test if $Proxies is an empty array, because 
# it will at the very least have "SMTP:$($NoweMail)"
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Clear ProxyAddresses
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = [string[]]$Proxies}

# or do this on one line:
# Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{proxyAddresses = [string[]]$Proxies}
```

<sup>Note that inside the hash to Add or Replace, the LDAP name is used, so `proxyAddresses` with a lowercase `p`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for Your efforts. It still not works as expected.
Clear does what it expected to do but Add generates the error
>Set-ADUser : Invalid type >'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection'
>Parameter name: proxyAddresses
>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CFOE:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

But the problem is still the same - old values in $Proxies are intacted. Only new value is added. Two SMTP occur.

Comment: @KrzychG Strange.. You might try `Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = [string[]]$Proxies}` or `Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $Proxies | ForEach-Object { "$_" }}`

Comment: @KrzychG Looks like the array needs to implement the Ienumerable interface. The above should then work, An alternative could be to convert the $Proxies array to a List of strings: `$newProxies = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$Proxies`. Then use this List object with `Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $newProxies}`

Comment: First approach works. But as I still point the problem is with inapropriate $Proxies value.

Comment: @KrzychG Sorry, I thought you meant to say that part of the code was OK. I have updated my answer to also deal with adding the new email address to the list

Answer (score 0):

@Theo. You solution works fine. Thank You for help.
I remained my approach (it suits me and works) and modified code a bit.

```
$ProxyOK = $false
$Proxies = $null
$Proxies = @()
$ADUser.ProxyAddresses | ForEach-Object {
  $_ = $_ -creplace 'SMTP', 'smtp'
  if ($_ -match $NoweMail) {
      $_ = $_ -creplace 'smtp', 'SMTP'
      $ProxyOK = $true
  }
  $Proxies += $_
}
if (!($ProxyOK)) { $Proxies += ("SMTP:$($NoweMail)") }
...
if ($Proxies) {
    $AttrToReplace.Add("ProxyAddresses", [string[]]$Proxies)
}
if ($AttrToReplace.Count -gt 0) {
    $Attr.Add("Replace", $AttrToReplace)
}
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountName -Server $ADDC @Attr #-PassThru -WhatIf
```